# Algorithm to classify 10 digit keys

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, integer, classification, business-intelligence

I'm looking for an algorithm that classifies differently formated 10 digit (mostly) integer keys. The training data set looks like that:

```
+------------+----------------+
|    key     | classification |
+------------+----------------+
| 1000012355 | US             |
| 1000045331 | US             |
| 0000123101 | DE             |
| 0003453202 | DE             |
| 000K213411 | ES             |
| 000K243221 | ES             |
+------------+----------------+
```

The keys originate from different systems and are created in a different manner. There is a large training data set available. While I assume that some part of those keys are random the structure is not.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can calculate the longest common substring for each category as the structure looks defined according to the example. 10000-> US, 000-> DE, 000K2->ES

Comment: how can keys coming from different systems where they are created in different manners be non-overlapping? most probably there is a system of ranges and codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before building models, training, and predicting.It's better to analyze the problem first, you assumed that some part of those keys are random the structure is not.You need to explore the data set to prove your hypothesis and according to the distribution of data, determine what model to use.

1. Converts a string to a vector, treat each character in a string as a categorical type feature，using one-hot encoding, you will get a sparse matrix of high dimensions. After this step, you can calculate, analyze, model, and so on for training data.
2. Then you need to analyze the data. One of the simple and effective methods is visual analysis.For high dimensional data, you can use the [*andrews curves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrews_plot), [*parallel coordinates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates)and so on.You can also use dimension reduction methods such as PCA or ICA, then visualize low dimensional data.
3. Depending on your visualization results, you can choose your model.If depending on the feature distribution, different categories of data are easily divided, you can use almost any classification algorithm, such as LR, SVM and even clustering.If it's a multi class problem, you can use OVO or OVR.If the visualization is poor, the distinction between classes is not obvious, you may need to do some feature engineering, or try tree models and ensemble learning methods.

Comment: It would certainly be best to understand the underlying structure. Failing that, or to check the results of such understanding, I would use a package like http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/ to try a number of different approaches, and I would be sure to include k-nearest neighbors, treating the numbers both as numbers (nearest is smallest absolute difference) and as arrays of digits (nearest is number with most corresponding digits the same).

Answer (score 0):

You could do a one-hot encoding of each character, and concatenate these.

That is, say you have 20 possible characters that each of these 10 characters in the key can take on. You could then convert each character to a 20-length vector of zeros, with a one in the position corresponding to the particular character. You would then have an overall feature vector of length 10 * 20 = 200. You could then feed this into any classification algorithm as inputs, with the target outputs being the possible countries.

If this is truly deterministic, and the keys can be separated, a decision tree might find the perfect solution. Or even logistic regression? If there is some 'fuzziness' then something like Random Forest might work better.